# Add listener to dynamically added HTML within closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of locations in google maps that a user can click. When they click, I generate a template that displays the information for that place. Right now, I have a container div that I call .replaceWith() on with the newly generated template.

When a user tries to click a button in that template, I want a place-specific action to take place (e.g. pin the place). To do this, I need the place ID saved somewhere so that the listener code knows what to do. I was hoping to use a closure to create the listener on the fly so that I could "enclose" the ID of the place that the viewer is getting details for:

```
function selectPlace(place_id) {

    // Swap out the old template
    $("#listing-placeholder").replaceWith(listing_info_template(place));

    // Create a listener to handle clicks while remembering the place_id
    (function(){
        $('.save_button').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked handler for " + place_id);
        });
    })();
}
```

This doesn't seem to work at all; my listener never fires. It seems like this is related to the fact that .save_button is inside of the template (dynamically added). Not sure why this is.

I am hesitant to use .on() because then I would have to put the ID somewhere in the template, which feels really hacky to me. I know that backbonejs somehow binds events to dynamically inserted templates so that any relevant context is still available to events -- that's effectively what I'm looking to mimic here.

So, any suggestions on how I can add a listener to a dynamically created element in such a way that the listener receives key information about the "object" that element is conceptually representing, without bloating the HTML with extra metadata (I've seen people make the id's like "save_button-" and then split on the dash, but that seems extremely hacky?)?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps investigate using Local Storage to maintain the state of the selected Id : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage. Then you can use jquerys' `on`

Comment: You're suggesting I store the ID somewhere in the HTML and then use that as an index into my localstorage, right? I've considered this but it feels wrong to have to store the ID in the html -- shouldn't there be a closure of sorts that can do this? Backbone seems to be able to bind object context to the HTML and listeners without inserting the ID into the html..

Comment: Not the HTML, but you have many options to store the selected ID. Local Storage,  create a variable with a boader scope, or as you mentioned in html (like a hidden field, but yes that is ugly) and probably a few more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a variable with a broad scope to hold selected Id in the quick and dirty example below.

```js
var selectedId; //Holds seleced ID

function selectPlace(place_id) {

  // Swap out the old template
  //$("#listing-placeholder").replaceWith(listing_info_template(place));
  $("#listing-placeholder").replaceWith($("#section" + place_id));
  //Sotre the ID here
  selectedId = place_id;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cbId").change(function() {
    selectPlace($(this).val())
  });

  //Set up event listener. Change #target as appropriate for you
  $("#target").on("click", ".save_button", function() {
    alert(selectedId);
  });

});
```

```css
#sections {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Select a section
    <select id="cbId">
      <option></option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="target">
  <div id="listing-placeholder">
    I'm the place holder
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sections">
  <!--No  Event Listeners Will be bound directly untill template is replaced -->
  <div id="section1">
    <h2>I'm section 1</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Save Button" class="save_button">
  </div>
  <div id="section2">
    <h2>I'm  section 2</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Save Button" class="save_button">
  </div>
  <div id="section3">
    <h2>I'm  section 3</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Save Button" class="save_button">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably easiest right now, I've considered doing this as well. I'm definitely more curious about how this would work if I had more than one item, though ( a list for instance). I'm still trying to figure out how to "bind" data for an object to a callback so that when I click on that item in the list, the callback has access to the relevant contextual data. BackboneJS seems to easily achieve this, but it seems really difficult if not impossible in normal Jquery?

Comment: Just remeber that variable can hold more than an Id. It can hold complex javascript objects if you need it too. Also look at data attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes and https://api.jquery.com/data/. Notice with the jquery api you can attach to the HTML body.

Comment: And as for comparing jquery with Backbone, you are comparing to frameworkds with vary different objetives. jquery if primarily focused on DOM manipulation while backbone is a MVP framework.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware they're different, was just curious if Backbone's pattern was ever hand-rolled with JQuery. I'm also really surprised that chsdk's answer (which is what I'm already doing) didn't work at all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Her's a quick demo with more complex data: https://jsfiddle.net/rcuhx1Ld/ . i've used data attributes holding data as JSON for the data here but the data is generic an could come from anywhere, an ajax call for example.

Answer (score 1):

I will just try to correct your actual approach by passing the parameter to your closure, but you may find a better approach.

In your case you need to pass the `place_id` as a parameter to the closure too, this is how should be your code:

```
function selectPlace(place_id) {

    // Swap out the old template
    $("#listing-placeholder").replaceWith(listing_info_template(place));

    // Create a listener to handle clicks while remembering the place_id
    (function(id){
        $('.save_button').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked handler for " + id);
        });
    })(place_id);
}
```

I changed the variable name so you can get the difference between the two parameters.

Comment: When I do this, the listener doesn't fire at all (no alert when I click), same as before.

Comment: This actualy mostly works (https://jsfiddle.net/jpn6kg34) but as a handler is added every time `selectPlace` is called you need to clear the handlers first (https://jsfiddle.net/jpn6kg34/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to use `.on`, it's the way jQuery matches all dynamically added elements. But you don't need to do anything "hacky", you just have to bind the listener to a parent element

```
`$(parent).on('click', '.save_button', {});
```

Comment: If i do this, i don't have any contextual information so when the listener fires I won't have the ID or other context information for the object. Is there a way around this without storing extra attributes on the HTML element itself? (that's what seems hacky to me)

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectPlace(place_id) {

    // Swap out the old template
    $("#listing-placeholder").replaceWith(listing_info_template(place));

    // Create a listener to handle clicks while remembering the place_id

        $(document).on('click', '.save_button').click(function(){
            alert("Clicked handler for " + place_id);
        }); 
}
```

Comment: If i do this, all the listeners add up and i end up with three "on" listeners if I have selected three items in the list. So the alert fires three times with three different id's, when it should only fire with the ID of the currently selected one.